# Append in Python Game

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
number_of_enemies = 5
enemies = []
for i in range(number_of_enemies):
    enemies.append(turtle.Turtle())
for enemy in enemies:
    enemy.shape(enemys)
    enemy.penup()
    enemy.speed(0)
    enemy.setposition(random.randint(-245, 245), random.randint(-245, 245))
```

I want to call on each enemy separately, but I don't know how to call them

Answer (score 2):

What exactly do you mean with "to call"?

`enemies[0]` To get the first enemy